# mail sent by exim are considered spam

Tags: email, spam, exim

I configured exim mail server to send email from my web application (Example recovers passwords).
Tests done by mail is always considered as spam.(i use gmail web client).
How do I configure exim so that the emails they send are not considered spam?

Header with SPF

```
Delivered-To: spidercloudfl@gmail.com
Received: by 10.194.81.69 with SMTP id y5csp12894wjx;
        Wed, 22 May 2013 10:34:21 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.15.107.77 with SMTP id ca53mr20828718eeb.40.1369244060917;
        Wed, 22 May 2013 10:34:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <info@wizardsnc.it>
Received: from 95.110.179.201 ([95.110.179.201])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id u46si3055346eeg.66.2013.05.22.10.34.20
        for <spidercloudfl@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 22 May 2013 10:34:20 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 95.110.179.201 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of info@wizardsnc.it) client-ip=95.110.179.201;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 95.110.179.201 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of info@wizardsnc.it) smtp.mail=info@wizardsnc.it
Received: (qmail 25578 invoked from network); 22 May 2013 18:33:20 +0100
Received: from localhost (HELO 95.110.179.201) (127.0.0.1)
  by localhost with ESMTPA; 22 May 2013 18:33:20 +0100
Date: Wed, 22 May 2013 18:33:20 +0100 (BST)
From: "Wizard s.n.c" <noreplay@wizardsnc.it>
To: "spidercloudfl@gmail.com" <spidercloudfl@gmail.com>
```

E-mail continue to be considered as spam :(.

thanks to all

Answer (score 7):

Modern large webmail providers use a reputation system to score and determine placement of inbound emails.  Your sending IP and domain name builds a reputation  How those reputation systems work *exactly* is not something that we on the outside will know.  But we can describe behaviors that seem to influence a sender's reputation.

1. If you have never sent an email from your IP, it has no reputation.  Unfortunately for you, no reputation is essentially in the border of a bad reputation.
2. If your IP has ever sent spam that one or more Gmail users submitted as spam, it contributes negatively to your reputation.
3. If an IP from your /24 (or maybe from the /n BGP announcement containing your IP), it contributes negatively to your reputation.  It is unknown if this is the same negativity as item #2.
4. If your domain does not have an SPF record, it contributes very negatively to your reputation.  If it does, and it does not match, it contributes negatively.  If it does have it and it does match, it contributes positively.
5. If your domain does not use DKIM to sign the emails, it contributes negatively to your reputation.  If your domain does and the signature fails, it contributes negatively.  If it does use DKIM and the signature passes, it contributes positively.
6. If your domain uses DMARC and it aligns, then it contributes positively to your reputation.  I think it contributes LARGELY positive.
7. If your emails are being marked as spam due to detected URLs in various URIBL's, it contributes negatively to your reputation.
8. If your IP's mail volume changes drastically upward, it contributes negatively to your reputation. It tends to be changes of scale.  So 0 to 5 may not be that big a deal, but 0 to 10 may be signs of abuse.  Same process for 100 to 500 ok, but 100 to 1000 is signs of abuse.
9. If your IP's mail volume is consistently the same, it will contribute positively to your reputation.
10. If your IP is listed in any major RBL, it contributes negatively to your reputation.
11. If your emails have invalid or missing required headers, it can contribute negatively to your reputation.
12. If your emails don't fall afoul of any of these things, it can contribute positively to your reputation.
13. If your emails are marked as Not Spam by users who receive it, it will contribute positively to your reputation.

Basically there are lots of things that can be wrong that contribute negatively, and just a few things that work for positive reputation.  There are more than these, but these are all I could think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

Todd's answer is good, and when he's talking about reputation, he's hitting the nail on the head.

Generally, not having SPF/DKIM/DMARC records has very little impact to your IP or domains reputation, and by extension, very little or no impact upon a particular messages deliverability. Take a look at the most widely deployed mail filters (SpamAssassin, Amavis) and you'll find that having matching SPF records provides no score increase. The same goes for DKIM. The reason for this is simple, it's very easy for spammers to publish SPF records and by harnessing the power of bot nets, the CPU cost of DKIM signing messages is negligible.

Many spammers use throw-away domains (no reputation) they acquire for this very purpose, generally in TLDs that permit domain abuse like .info, .pw, .tw, and .biz. Just like Todd's points #2, and #3, if you happen to have a domain that is surrounded by spammers, it's just as bad as having an IP address or ASN with spammy neighbors.

SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are all *authentication* mechanisms. They serve only to validate that the domain in question is responsible for a particular message. The reason a domain owner with a good reputation *should* publish a SPF record and DKIM sign their messages is to prevent spammers from sending emails from their domain, and thereby sullying their good reputation.

Failing SPF, DKIM, and DMARC will definitely earn you negative points, in varying quantities.

I'm on a couple DMARC mailing lists and I run one of about 20 mail systems on the internet that do DMARC reporting. I don't know of anyone handing out extra ham points for DMARC aligned messages. That isn't to say DMARC is not helpful. If your domain has a good reputation, and you publish DMARC records and a particular message is aligned, then your good reputation extends to that message. If the message is not aligned, then we have to decide if the message really is from you, and how much of your domains reputation should be afforded it.

Another thing that's vitally important for a mail servers reputation is having properly configured DNS. Make absolutely certain your mail server's IP has matching forward and reverse DNS (FCrDNS), and that the hostname of the server is configured correctly, and that Exim is using the machines hostname.

Comment: I upvoted your comment.  I think you completely covered the non-reputation side of email, and you did it well! Your answer combined with my reputation answer is an accurate view of how receivers may see/evaluate inbound emails. You may want to add that "SPF/DKIM are useful for confirming email you _already_ think might be good, is actually from who it says it is. It's not so great at detecting that email is definitely bad." DMARC does bridge some of those shortcomings because it allows a domain owner to get feedback of how others evaluated an email (claiming to be) from them.